# Agravitee & WebSockets - HTTP headers not passed to backend server

Tags: websocket, gravitee

I would like to use WebSockets over Gravitee API Gateway. I'm able to establish the WebSocket connection but I have a problem with HTTP headers. Seems Gravitee doesn't pass HTTP headers from the client to the backend server. This happens e.g. for Authorization and Cookie headers.

I'm using Gravitee 3.15.3. Keyless plan for the WebSocket communication.

**Update**
Related Gravitee question: https://community.gravitee.io/t/apim3-websockets-stomp-security-copying-http-headers-for-ws/696

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been reported here: https://github.com/gravitee-io/issues/issues/7750

And the fix has been merged and released in APIM 3.15.10+